# if else short hand failed in PHP

Tags: php

```
<input type="submit" value="<? get_the_category( $id )[0]->name == 'English' ? echo 'Find' : echo 'encontrar'; ?>">
```

Not sure what is my problem here, I have problem doing a shorthand of if else condition.

Comment: The ternary operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary evaluates to an expression. So just put `echo` at the start of the ternary and remove them in the ternary

Comment: Just one echo on `? :`

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you can't use echo that way since it has no return type.

You can try either of these:

```
<?php echo (get_the_category( $id )[0]->name == 'English') ? 'Find' : 'encontrar'; ?>
```

OR

```
<? get_the_category( $id )[0]->name == 'English' ? print 'Find' : print 'encontrar'; ?>
```